# How to find index of array of records return from database in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am getting array of records from sql query now I want to find whether current users record is present in that array of records and at which position. So I wrote following query but it is returning null.

```
@top_score_cards = Score.group(:points).distinct.order("points DESC, updated_at DESC").where("points != ? And activity_id= ?",0,params[:@myActivity])#.limit(3)
@current_users_rank=@top_score_cards.index(current_user)

puts @current_users_rank
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

top_score_cards.include?(current_user.id)

you can use pluck to directly convert a database result into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your above query isn't including any user information, so I'm only assuming your `User` model has some sort of relation to `Score`.

If that's the case, your `@current_users_rank` method needs to include that relation value, and not the plain `current_user` object:

`@current_users_rank = @top_score_cards.index(current_user.score)`

Hope this helps!